# Using Pt-online schema change on multi master MYSQL

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-toolkit

We are using two MYSQL servers in ring replication where master is also a slave of the other master. Both have slaves connected to each other.
We want to run pt-online-schema-change to add couple of columns but we are not sure if it may break the replication due to ring replication in place. Any advice would be great.

Comment: I got lost on "slaves connected to each other".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a dsn table as a recursion method, then pt-online-schema-change can do the job for you. This is documented here:

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html#cmdoption-pt-online-schema-change-recursion-method

If you use the hosts method, though, pt-osc will detect that SHOW SLAVE STATUS returns more than 1 row, but it considers the topology is using replication channels. You would get this error:

```
This server returned more than one row for SHOW SLAVE STATUS but "channel"
was not specified on the command line at bin/pt-online-schema-change line 4494.
```

For setting up topologies to test different circumstances, dbdeployer is a useful tool https://github.com/datacharmer/dbdeployer#replication-topologies.

*Disclosure: I work for Percona*

Comment: As an aside, overall the use of ring replication isn't thought to be ideal. You may have a specific need (or might have inherited it), I realize. Here is a discussion on that https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/10/07/mysql-ring-replication-why-it-is-a-bad-option/

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your feedback. I agree with you that this tool will not work, perhaps we can call it a bug as there is no channel replication setup, instead its a ring. Though I just joined them 2 days ago and was curious as if this can occur. I am in process of taking ring replication out of the scenario but will take time to convince the client. Thanks for pointing out though!

Comment: No problem I have added this to our bug reports if you want to follow it https://jira.percona.com/browse/PT-1505

Comment: Hi again, one of our team observed an alternative way of using pt-osc to do what you need, I have updated the answer. Hope this helps.